# Count click of every link in the page

Tags: javascript, aura

On a record page there is a standard rich-text component. An image is added to the rich-text field and it is hyperlinked. I have to capture the number of click on this hyperlinked image on the page.

I am using a code snippet in my another existing aura component (In the same page) where I am using `window.addEventListener` to get the every click on the page primarily. Now when clicking on the **image** of that rich text field, the click is listened but not able to get the url/href value of that image. Can anyone please help me here?

```
({
    listenClick : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        window.addEventListener("click", function(){
            
            alert('Click is listening');
            // Get all anchor tags on the page 
            var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
            
            // Loop through all the links and attach an event listener to each 
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
                links[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) { 
                    // Prevent the default link behavior 
                    event.preventDefault(); 

                    alert('Link clicked: ' + event.target.href); // Not getting the url here
                }); 
            } 
        });

    }
})
```

[image]